# Id can't pass through link using the jquery function

Tags: jquery

In this code the Id & Name values are get correctly but in link the value id not in format

```
function onStudentDivisionChange() {
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        dataType : 'json',
        url : '/sample/selectDivision.html',
        data : ({
            id : $('#division').val()
        }),
        success : function(responseData) {

            if (responseData != null) {

                $('#student').find('td').remove().end().append('').val('-1');
                $.each(responseData, function(index, item) {

                    $('#student').append(   
                        $('<td></td>').val(item['id']).html(item['id']),

                        $('<td></td>').val(item['id']).html(item['name']),

                        $('<td></td>').val(item['id']).html(
                             '<a th:href="@{/teacher/edit.html(id=${id})}" >Edit</a>'),

                        $('<br />').val(item['id']).html(item['']));

                });
            } else {
               $('#stud').find('td').remove().end().append('<td  th:text="${student}"></td>').val('-1');
                        }
        }

    });
}
```

**Problem** was in the

```
`<a th:href="@{/teacher/edit.html(id=${id})}" >Edit</a>`

                                        ^
                                        |__ value of Id is get as id in alphabet. = id 
 Not the student id  number or Integer
```

The value of id can not get here..

i don't know this is right . if any one know about this please share here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following :

```
'<a th:href="@{/teacher/edit.html(id=${' + item['id'] + '})}" >Edit</a>'
```

This will append in the value of ID from the item object.

Comment: Sorry to say this code generate error & the error is

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "' + item['id'] + '"

Comment: I've never heard of that, are you using something other than jQuery? If so please remember to tag everything in your question.

Comment: sorry and am using thymeleaf page and inside that using jquery function using combobox for iteration

Comment: I'm afraid I've never heard of `thymeleaf` so I don't think I'll be able to help you with this. Sorry.